# Issue showing decimal places in X axis - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've this issue with this graph,

Below the code:

```
axex=[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
axey=[0.15686275, 0.28808446, 0.53242836, 1.        , 1.        ,
       1.        , 1.        ]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
#x = [0.00001,0.001,0.01,0.1,0.5,1,5]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
plt.plot(axex,axey ,'o-', linestyle='--', label='Results')
plt.title("Show Test")
plt.xlabel("X Axis")
plt.ylabel("Y Axis")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Whats's happening, is the values of "axex" and the line are not correctly displayed in the graph, 
It's not displaying in the axex scale (0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0)

If we run the graph without axex on the plot, we get the correct line graph, but the scale of x axis is not correctly displayed.

How can we fix this ?

Comment: Clearly the graph is correct. Maybe you want to use a logarithmic scale instead?

Comment: Try `plt.xscale('log')`.

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho  I've formalized an answer below. Please mark it as "accepted" if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are two lists of numerical values, then `plot(x,y)` will plot all the coordinates `(x[0], y[0])`, `(x[1], y[1])`, ..., and so on, and by default, it will only use linear axes. `plot(x,y)` will *not* change the scale of the axes depending on the numerical values of the data stored in `x` and `y`.

One way to get a logarithmic scale, is to use `pyplot.xscale('log')` and/or equivalently for the y-scale, `yscale('log')`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axex=[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
axey=[0.15686275, 0.28808446, 0.53242836, 1., 1., 1., 1.]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(axex, axey, linestyle='--', label='Results')
plt.xscale('log') # Set log scale on X-axis
plt.title("Show Test")
plt.xlabel("X Axis")
plt.ylabel("Y Axis")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you furthermore want to customize which ticks on the x axis are labeled (and those labels), you can use [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html). [minor_ticks_off](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=tick#matplotlib.pyplot.minorticks_off) can also be useful in that case.